# Windows Phone 8 SDK WebClient Encoding Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse html from a site using windows-1254 charset. but all Turkish characters shown like this: � � � � �

Where is the actual problem? I did try these:

```
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetString("UTF-8");
```

as function this:

```
public string ReplaceText(string _text)
        {
            _text = _text.Replace("Ä°", "İ").Replace("Ä±", "ı").Replace("Ã&frac14;", "ü").Replace("ÅŸ", "ş").Replace("Å", "Ş").Replace("Ã§", "ç").Replace("Ã¶", "ö").Replace("ÄŸ", "ğ").Replace("Ã‡", "Ç").Replace("Ã–", "Ö").Replace("Ãœ", "Ü");
            return _text;
        }
```

also this headers:

```
webClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
webClient.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "windows-1254,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
```

(with iso-8859-9, utf8 too)

and this is how i am using the webclient:

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();         
            wb.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
            wb.Headers["Accept-Charset"] = "windows-1254,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
            wb.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.site.com"));
            wb.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wb.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DSC);
```

handler:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(e.Result);

            var inputs = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id=\"mrln-eyhaber\"]//a");

            foreach (var input in inputs)
            {

                textarea.Text += this.ReplaceText(input.Attributes["title"].Value.ToString()) + "\n\n";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using standard approach, why don you create a custom class, specific for your needs, which will handle the etconding.

[This](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) will help you generate the class, like so:[image]

and then all you have to do

```
webClient.Encoding = CustomEncoding();
```

Let me know how it goes (:

Comment: can you give me some more information about how do i use it? i created a new class and added the code `using Hardcodet.Silverlight.Util;` then how will i use it with webClient.Encoding ?

Comment: oh god sorry i got it just added `new CustomEncoding();` and its working now! thank you so much here is your bountry :)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you set the Encoding to UTF-8 if you know its windows-1254? 
The fix is rather easy, you just have to set the correct encoding in the `WebClient`.

```
wb.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
```

or

```
wb.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
```

Also, your `ReplaceText` method shouldn't be needed anymore either.

EDIT: Of course, Windows Phone doesn't support that encoding just like that, you have to implement any encoding other than utf-8 or utf-16 yourself. Luckily there's an easy way to do that, you just have to use the programm described [here](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator) to generate your own encoding class.

Comment: Sure I did. It says exactly this: `System.ArgumentException: 'windows-1254' is not a supported encoding name.`