# c# windows phone -- text box doesn't understand foreign characters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone

I'm building an app to access Google Translate for Windows Phone. I've noticed that for languages where the translated words will have foreign characters, the text box gets all screwed up and instead displays random symbols and such. Not sure why. Do I need to enable something on the text box?

Code:

```
private void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = txtboxOriginal.Text;
        string fromLanguage;
        string toLanguage;
        //Use Bing.
        if ((bool)settings["translateIsBing"] == true)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't translate with nothing to translate. Please try again.");
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        //Use Google.
        else if ((bool)settings["translateIsGoogle"] == true)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't translate with nothing to translate. Please try again.");
            }
            else
            {
                fromLanguage = this.getLanguageCodeGoogle(lstOriginalLanguages.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                toLanguage = this.getLanguageCodeGoogle(lstTranslateToLanguages.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                string url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_t?text=" + text + "&sl=" + fromLanguage + "&tl=" + toLanguage;
                WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
                webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
                webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
        }

    }

void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Result);
                string result = e.Result;
                int startPosition = result.IndexOf("TRANSLATED_TEXT='");
                int length = result.IndexOf(@"';INPUT") - startPosition;
                string partial = result.Substring(startPosition, length);
                Debug.WriteLine("Step 1: {0}", partial);
                startPosition = partial.IndexOf("'") + 1;
                length = partial.Length - startPosition;
                string secondPartial = partial.Substring(startPosition, length);
                Debug.WriteLine("Step 2: {0}", secondPartial);
                translatedText = secondPartial;
                txtboxOriginal.Text = secondPartial;
                btnTranslate.Content = "Translated";
                btnTranslate.IsEnabled = false;
                btnCopy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnCopy.IsEnabled = true;
                btnReset.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnReset.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues is could by the encoding type of the response from Google.
When you look at the Content-type of the response it isn't UTF8 always which what WebClient.DownloadStringAsync decodes it to so you have to change the decoding type

You will have to change the `Webclient.Encoding` to match the request type

The solution to the problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073787/windows-phone-8-sdk-webclient-encoding-issue)