# IBM Mobile First Vietnamese characters(Special Characters) in JSON not supported in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, json, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-mobilefirst-windows

In my IBM mobile first application, JSON response with Vietnamese Character (Ex: Tôi là một nhân vật đặc biệt) in Windows 8.1 Phone is not working.

My char encoding is UTF-8.

**`resourceRequest.send($scope.dataToSendArr).then($rootScope.success, $rootScope.fail);`**

This stops working after this line and not calls success or neither fail, even don't go in the catch block.  This works when I send JSON in English without Vietnamese character.

It works on Android and iOS with Vietnamese character.

So, how would I support Vietnamese Character or Special Character  JSON response in Windows 8.1 phone ?

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/save", WLResourceRequest.POST);
resourceRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
resourceRequest.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
resourceRequest.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
resourceRequest.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');

//Gets Unresponsive after this line.               
resourceRequest.send($scope.dataToSendArr).then($rootScope.success, $rootScope.fail);
```

Comment: Can you check if Vietnamese language support is available on the phone?

Comment: @VivinK yes phone supports Vietnamese language.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with cyrillic alphabet. The way that i deal with it was with creating of custom encoding. Please can you check my approach:  [Windows Phone 8 SDK WebClient Encoding Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073787/windows-phone-8-sdk-webclient-encoding-issue)

Encoding name: **Windows-1258**